# Exporting QGIS shp file to dxf-Which dxf format?

Tags: qgis, export, dxf

As I understand it, dxf comes in a range of format types. QGIS (v2.0 'Dufour') can export any layer to a dxf file. However I have a hydraulic modelling package which relies upon importing the dxf file as the R12 format.

This import does not seem to work. I was wondering which dxf format does QGIS export to? If it is not R12, this may be the reason why this is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS is built with GDAL/OGR which exports to [AutoCAD 2000 DXF](http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html) format (which means so does the [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) utility).  I don't know what version GRASS writes to (in Processing Toolbox), so that may be worth some research.  If you get stuck [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dxfwrite/) is a Python library that writes to R12.  You would need to write a script to import [ogr](http://www.gdal.org/) or [shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) (or similar) to read your geometry and then implement a loop to cycle through the features and punt them out to your R12 file.